# Memory increase when convert UIView to Image

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, image, memory-leaks

I have horizontal `UIView` in `ScrollView` with some big sized images. I want to split as particular sizes like carousel post.
But, when I execute the function it crash the application, becuase of low memory. I check that, When I Render Preview it use large amount ot memory.
I used bellow code for generate images from view.

```
func generatePreviewImages() -> [UIImage] {
        let arrMaskView = properties.arrAllObjectView.filter({ ($0 as? MaskView) != nil }) as? [MaskView] ?? [MaskView]()
        
        arrMaskView.forEach({ $0.imageViewAddIcon.isHidden = true })
        
        var arrImage = [UIImage]()
        for i in 0..<Int(properties.cols) {
            autoreleasepool(invoking: {
                let x = (viewCanvas.frame.size.width / properties.cols.cgFloat) * CGFloat(i)
                let width = (viewCanvas.frame.size.width / properties.cols.cgFloat)
                if let image = viewCanvas.asImage(bounds: CGRect.init(x: x, y: 0, width: width, height: viewCanvas.bounds.height)) {
                    arrImage.append(image)
                }
            })
        }
        
        arrMaskView.forEach({ $0.imageViewAddIcon.isHidden = !($0.imageUser == nil) })
        
        return arrImage
}
```

For Converted Images from UIView

```
func asImage(bounds:CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is holding all images in an array and that is the main cause of memory pressure here. Images are created in memory(RAM) and that's why you are getting memory warning here.

All you can do is, after creating the image in for loop, save the created image onto disk memory i.e. in Documents Directory or somewhere else and save the file url of saved image into array. Later you can load images from disk memory and can use wherever you want.

Hope this solve your problem!!!

Comment: But my problem is that when generating image from view then it will increasing memory.